# Working with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these 4 tables with different rows and columns and I need to get certain values. I am having some difficulty with a few and cannot seem to get it.

`customers` table:

- customerID: integer
- fName: string
- lName: string

`items` table:

- itemID: integer
- description: string
- price: float

`orders` table:

- orderID: integer
- itemID: integer
- aID: integer
- customerID: integer
- date: date

`addresses` table:

- aID: integer
- housenum: integer
- streetName: string
- town:string
- state: string
- zip:integer

The values I am looking to get are:

1. List the `itemID` and `description` of all items for which there is only one order.

   Now I can get the `itemID` and `description`, however I am not sure how to nail it down to items only ordered once. I am thinking of using `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` but I cannot seem to find the correct combination.

   ```
     SELECT itemID, 
            description 
       FROM items 
   GROUP BY itemID
   ```
2. List all customers who have shipped items to multiple addresses.

   This one I have to use `JOIN` somehow, since the `customerID` would be the same but not the address?

   ```
   SELECT customerID, 
          streetName, 
          housenum 
     FROM addresses 
     JOIN customers 
       ON addresses.streetName = customers.customerID
   ```
3. Return the total revenue generated by all of the orders.

   Couldn't I just use:

   ```
   SELECT SUM(price), 
          orderID 
     FROM items 
     JOIN orders 
       ON orders.orderID = items.price ?
   ```
4. List the first and last names of all customers who have had the same item shipped to at least two different addresses.

   ```
   SELECT fName, 
          lName, 
          itemID, 
          streetName, 
          housenum 
     FROM addresses, 
          customers, 
          items, 
   somehow join multiple(2+)?
   ```

Comment: No attempt at writing a SQL query. Why should I try?

Comment: Yes I have some examples, I wasnt sure if I should input them since they did not work, I will paste em now, sorry about that

Comment: You have had six minutes to paste them .....

Comment: I just edited them into my OP

Comment: Looks like a school assignment to me.

Comment: yep part of an EC course I am in to get familiar with Computer programming for web dev before I enter college

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may not be right with all the queries but I have found the items listed on the question very interesting and decided to give it a try.

1. items sold only once

   ```
      SELECT o.itemID, 
             i.description 
        FROM orders o 
   LEFT JOIN items i
          ON i.id = o.itemID
    GROUP BY o.itemID
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
   ```

   On this query, you need to join the the `items` table in order to retrieve the `description` and `GROUP BY` it by the `itemID` so you can specifically use `COUNT` for each `itemID` which we can then use with `HAVING` to obtain on the ones with 1 order.
2. Customer that have shipped to diff address

   ```
      SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT addressID) as diff_address,
             c.fName,
             c.lName
        FROM orders o
   LEFT JOIN customers c
          ON o.customerID = c.id
    GROUP BY o.customerID
      HAVING diff_address > 1;
   ```

   Here I am using the DISTINCT function to eliminate duplicated address and `GROUP BY` the `customerID` so I can have a list of unique address per customer and again using `HAVING` we get the customers that have shipped products with more than 1 different address. Am also using `JOIN` on the customer table to obtain their needed information.
3. Total revenue

   ```
      SELECT SUM(i.price) as total
        FROM orders o
   LEFT JOIN items i
          ON o.itemID = i.id;
   ```

   I guess this one is the simplest one here, by using `JOIN` on the items table, I am able to read each item `price` which I can then sum per order to have a gran total of sales.
4. List of customers that have shipped the same item to at least 2 different address

   ```
     SELECT c.fName,
            c.lName,
            COUNT(oi.itemID) AS `total items with diff address >= 2`
       FROM customers c
       JOIN (SELECT customerID,
                    itemID,
                    COUNT(DISTINCT addressID) AS diff_address
               FROM orders
           GROUP BY itemID, customerID
             HAVING diff_address >= 2
            ) AS oi
         ON oi.customerID = c.id
   GROUP BY c.id;
   ```

   This one was the most complicated one, hope I can explain it. First I started it with the sub-query where I can list all items per customer that have multiple address, then by using `JOIN` on the `customerID` I can count how many different items that given customer have shipped with 2 or more diff address.

[Here is a **LIVE DEMO.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85ffd/30/3)

If you see any of the queries are not good or have any advice kindly do tell me so I can improve it.

Comment: could you send me an email at thrgk@aol.com? i had a few questions just needed to clarify.

Comment: @user3321452 make a new question which is specific to what you wish to know(as this one question was rather broad with different items) and I am sure the community will clarify that to you.

Comment: new thread made http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22134192/using-queries-for-specific-data-out-of-tables