# Using queries for specific data out of tables

Tags: sql

I need some help finding data from some tables. I want to se SQL queries to find it, however I am having some difficulty doing it.

```
customers (customerID: integer, fName: string, lName: string)
items (itemID: integer, description: string, price: float)
orders (orderID: integer, itemID: integer, aID: integer, customerID: integer, date: date)
addresses (aID: integer, housenum: integer, streetName: string, town:string, state: string, zip:integer)
```

1. For each zipcode, list the zipcode and the total value of items shipped to the zipcode.

This is what I have tried, however I am not sure it is correct since many of the SUM(price) are the same?

```
SELECT DISTINCT(zip), SUM(price)
FROM addresses, items
GROUP BY zip
```

1. List the town, first name, and last name of any customer who has shipped an item to the same town as another customer.

   ```
   SELECT fName, lName, town, aID
   FROM customers
   JOIN addresses
   ON addresses.town=customers.lName
   FROM addresses
   ON addresses.aID=customers.fName
   ```

Lastly 3. Return the average amount of money each customer spent in March of 2013. (Note that the answer will be a single number).

Thanks so much

Comment: "Note that the answer will be a single number"  Sounds like homework.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? And by the way: `distinct` is **not** a function. `DISTINCT(zip)` does not make any sense, *especially* when you are also grouping on the `zip` column

Comment: I was trying to use DISTINCT(zip) to show only each zip code once?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a homework, but here's something to get you started:

> 1. For each zipcode, list the zipcode and the total value of items shipped to the zipcode.

Each item belongs to an order and each order has an address.

SQL:

```
SELECT a.zip, sum(i.prices)
FROM items i
JOIN orders o using(orderID)
JOIN addresses a using(aID)
GROUP by a.zip
```

> 1. List the town, first name, and last name of any customer who has shipped an item to the same town as another customer.

Each customer has orders and each order has an address.

SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.town, 
            c.fname, 
            c.lname 
FROM   customer c 
   JOIN orders o 
     ON c.customerid = o.customerid 
   JOIN addresses a 
     ON o.aid = a.aid 
WHERE  town IN (
            SELECT town 
            FROM   orders o 
                   JOIN addresses a 
                     ON o.aid = a.aid 
            GROUP BY town 
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.customerid) > 1)
```

Comment: I could not get the last one to work, it gives no errors but does not get any results, eventhough there are results to give off. I tried messing around but didnt get it to work, ill keep trying. Thanks for your help!